# Slick.js margins on active slide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

I'm using a Slick slideshow. I applied a scale 2 to the active slide, but when the size of slide changes, the margins on the right and left don't move. How can I fix that?

An example where I found the margins working on active slide: https://codepen.io/jinzagon/pen/KKzaQwz

My code: https://codepen.io/jinzagon/pen/YzqpdLj

HTML

```html
<section class="top_slider">
  <div>
    <a href="google.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=2">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=3">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=4">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1">
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```css
.slider {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 100px auto;
  height: auto!important;
}

.slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
  width: 80%;
  transition: all linear 0.4s;
}

.slick-center img {
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: all linear 0.4s;
}
```

JS

```js
$(".top_slider").slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
});

$('html').animate({
  scrollTop: $('.top_slider').offset().top
}, 500);
```

Comment: You are scaling the image, they are scaling the slide. Please note that changing the slide's transform will cause issues as in the example of jinzagon. Also, they are changing the slick CSS to use `display: flex` instead of `float`. If you prefer flex I suggest you to use Swiper slider instead, as it is modern slider than slick.

Comment: @Rado I see. So is there any other alternative to do so ? I just want to run the Slick Slide, don't care about the display.

Comment: If you remove the `.slick-center` styles, it will work normally. If you want a transform of the active slide, we have to find a workaround.

Comment: Are you talking in my example or Jinzagon example ?

Comment: When you remove the styles `.slick-center img { transform: scale(2); transition: all linear 0.4s; } Slick is working normally.

Comment: Yes, but I do want the size-up while a slide is active. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I have mimic it with scaling all the slides with scale of 50% and the active slide with scale of 100%. Also, add inner div with class `.slide` so we can place transformations on it. That way, we do not interfere with slick calculations.

You can play with the scale values to make it as you wish.

```js
$(".top_slider").slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
});

$('html').animate({
  scrollTop: $('.top_slider').offset().top
}, 500);
```

```css
.slider {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 100px auto;
  height: auto!important;
}

.slide {
  transform: scale(.5);
  transition: transform linear 0.15s;
}

.slick-center .slide {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.slick-list {
  overflow: visible;
}


/* This should be included in your reset/normalize file */

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />

<section class="top_slider">
  <div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=4">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=5">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Although the margin is a bit too much, I would prefered a smaller margin between elements.

Comment: You could make `.slide { transform: scale(.8); }` That way, the imitation of margins will be smaller.

Comment: I see, but i can't modify the margins otherwise ?

Comment: The idea is that you are scaling only the inner element and the parent keeps its sizes. That way, we don't change the parent's size (in this case `.slick-slide`) and we don't interfere with slick calculations. At the moment there is no space between slides. You can add margins if you want, but this will increase even more the visual gap between the slides.

Comment: I perfectly understood what you did. I will have to thank you !